# Moving fields within in Ruby on Rails select list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ibm-midrange

I would like to arrange the fields that build a select list in the following query. In the second query I would like cnam05 to be listed first however the query breaks when I adjust the order

```
def self.get_states parmstate,parmrep
records = SignOn.find_by_sql ["SELECT DISTINCT CAD505 cad505 FROM SIGNCUSTM2 WHERE CAD505<>'' AND TRTY20 = ? ORDER BY CAD505", parmrep] 
return nil if records[0].blank?

records.map { |r| "#{r.cad505}" }
end

def self.get_stores parmstate,parmrep
records = SignOn.find_by_sql ["SELECT CNAM05 cnam05, CAD105 cad105, CAD405 cad405, CUSN05 cusn05 FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE CAD505 = ? AND TRTY20 = ? ORDER BY CNAM05, CUSN05", parmstate, parmrep]
return nil if records[0].blank?

records.map { |r| "#{r.cusn05}~ #{r.cnam05} - #{r.cad105}, #{r.cad405}" }
end
```

thank you for the suggestion it makes a lot more sense

Now I am getting the following returned error

```
ERROR: missing customer record for cusn05 = YANKEE PUPPY                       

NoMethodError (undefined method `cusn05' for nil:NilClass):
app/models/customer.rb:31:in `company'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:167:in `set_session_variables'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:92:in `require_distributor'
```

I am thinking that I need a way to retain the value of cusn05 without displaying it in the drop down values.

Any insight or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't use `x = 0; while x < s.length; ...; x+=1`. Use `d = s.map`. The idiomatic Ruby way is much, *much* shorter: http://pastebin.com/3Ah2LXJw

Comment: Please delete the code. It's not Rails way!https://gist.github.com/itsNikolay/b2333d9a42d774016fc0

Comment: why are you writing the query by hand, when you should be using Active Record find or where

Comment: unfortunately this is an app that I have inherited and I have not been given the project time to rewrite it. I am more of a php guy and just learning my way around ruby on the fly.

Comment: ok modified the model and now I am getting the following the view:
ActionView::TemplateError (undefined local variable or method `s' for SignOn(Table doesn't exist):Class) on line #11 of app/views/user_sessions/store.html.erb:
8:    <%= hidden_field_tag "nav" %>
9:    
10:    <p align="center">
11:     <strong>Store:</strong>&nbsp;<%= select_tag :store_id, options_for_select(SignOn.get_stores $selectedstate,$selectedrep) %>
12:    </p>
13:    
14:    <p>

Comment: IF you are a PHP guy, why did you accept the project?

Comment: because everything else is in php and they had contracted out for this project and the long and short is that I am salary and stuck with it

Answer (score 1):

In this piece of your code:

```
records.map { |r| "#{s.cusn05}~ #{r.cnam05} - #{r.cad105}, #{r.cad405}" }
```

What is this "s" you're using on the first parameter inside the block?
It should probably be "r".

(The same thing happens 7 lines under this line's firs appearance).

**UPDATE**:

So here are some insights:

- As has been pointed out, you are writing weird queries (and models). I suggest you take a look at it, it might help you greatly: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html
- The errors you're having are pretty self-explanatory, so there isn't much we can do to help, other than just re-write that for you, which I'm sure you don't need. For example, this new error you're having reads:

> ERROR: missing customer record for cusn05 = YANKEE PUPPY
>   NoMethodError (undefined method `cusn05' for nil:NilClass):

Which means that there's no record for the attribute you passed, so, you're receiving 'nil' back, and 'nil' obviously doesn't have a method called 'cusn05'.

- Not trying to be philosophical here, but, really, the way you're writing your code suggests you would benefit greatly from an overall read about Ruby and Rails. There are inumerous guides and books around.

As for your immediate problem, yeah, the record wasn't found, so you received 'nil' back and you're calling the method 'cusn05' on 'nil', breaking your code.

I apologize for so many words, but here's for trying to give some insights that might help you on the long run =]

Comment: the query works...

 def self.get_stores parmstate,parmrep
records = SignOn.find_by_sql ["SELECT CNAM05 cnam05, CAD105 cad105, CAD405 cad405, CUSN05 cusn05, PRFDSTW1 prfdstw1 FROM SIGNCUSTM2 WHERE CAD505 = ? AND TRTY20 = ? ORDER BY CNAM05, CUSN05", parmstate, parmrep]
return nil if records[0].blank?

records.map { |r| "#{r.cusn05}~ #{r.cnam05} - #{r.cad105}, #{r.cad405}, #{r.prfdstw1}" }
end ...  

the only issue is that I want cnam05 to be first and cusn05 to be last and when I switch the orderI get the error listed above

Comment: this is the model that the error is ref........def self.company query_account_number
  customer = Customer.first(:conditions => {:cusn05 => query_account_number}, :select => 'CONO05 cono05')
  customer.cono05
 end
......most of these have been written this way an it predates dates me how should they look?...this would help going forward but at the moment I am more concerned with why the order of the fields break the query

Comment: I am wondering is there a way to just hide cusn05 from displaying in the drop down but still have the value? something like 
#{r.cusn05.hide}

Comment: I know in html you can have hidden values but not sure if that would work in this instance or not or whether it needs to be handled in the model instead of view

Comment: I was talking to someone over the weekend and he suggested rethinking my logic and at his suggestion:  def index
 (at)customers = Customer.where("CAD505=? AND TRYT20=?", parmstate, parmrep).where.not(cusn05: nil)
end and in the view: where.not(cusn05: nil)
end ---and in the view: <% @customers.each do |customer| %>
<div>
   <%= customer.cnam05 %>
  
</div>
<% end %> --- This feels closer but I think I am still missing something?? Can anyone see what I am missing here?

Comment: the error that I am getting now is: ActionView::TemplateError (undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass) on line #10 of app/views/user_sessions/store.html.erb:
7:     
8:    <%= hidden_field_tag "nav" %>
9:    
10:    <% @customers.each do |customer| %>
11: 
12:     <div>
13: